# What does the Gnosis-Safe UI is looking for accepting a contract as a Safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I want to modify the safe code but I want to be able to use it in the UI, so what the UI is looking at ? The ABI ? The bytecode ? The contract Name ?

thks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI uses an indexing service which traces internal transactions and events to determine supported contracts. Only specific contracts are accepted. You can retrieve them via https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io/api/v1/about/master-copies/